# How do I get the name of the slider in the callback function of the jquery ionrangeslider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jquery-ui-slider, ion-range-slider

The example script:

```
<input type="text" class="js-range-slider" name="sliderNo1" />
<input type="text" class="js-range-slider" name="sliderNo2" />
<input type="text" class="js-range-slider" name="sliderNo3" />


$(".js-range-slider").ionRangeSlider({
    skin:"big",
    min:"0",
    max:"10", 
    placeholder:"none",
    hide_min_max:"true",

    onChange: function(data) {
      console.log('name of this active slider: ');
    }

});
```

I would like to read the name of the active slider in the callback function. How can I get this attribute at this point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `data.input[0].name` to get the active slider name like this.

```
$(".js-range-slider").ionRangeSlider({
    skin:"big",
    min:"0",
    max:"10", 
    placeholder:"none",
    hide_min_max:"true",

    onChange: function(data) {   
      console.log('name of this active slider: ' + data.input[0].name);
    }

});
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much for this.
How do I get the associated index of the (.js-range-slider) class from the slider? That would also be nice to find out. I would also need that at various points.

Comment: If you want to get the active `.js-range-slider` you can get it using attribute selector like this `$(".js-range-slider[name='"+data.input[0].name+"']")`. Is it what do you want?

Comment: I was looking for exactly that:
`var obj = $ (". js-range-slider [name = '" + data.input [0] .name + "']");
       console.log ($ ( '. js-range slider') index (obj).);`
Thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: You're welcome. Mark my answer as solved if it worked for you. Thank you :)